# Regular Expression - 12/22

Tags: javascript, regex, yii

I want to validate credit card expiration date something like that  Which allows me to input valid current year to future

```js
var regex = /^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(0[1-3]|1[0-9])$/

console.log('12/17', regex.test('12/17'))
console.log('12/22', regex.test('12/22'))
console.log('12/25', regex.test('12/25'))
console.log('00/18', regex.test('00/18'))
console.log('01/38', regex.test('01/38'))
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the year fragment of the regex. Could be something like this?

`^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(1[7-9]|[2-4]\d)$`

```js
var regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(1[7-9]|[2-4]\d)$/

console.log('12/25', regex.test('12/25'))
console.log('13/25', regex.test('13/25'))
console.log('01/18', regex.test('01/18'))
console.log('00/18', regex.test('00/18'))
console.log('00/18', regex.test('01/38'))
```

Comment: And what about 12/31

Comment: Until what year do you want?

Comment: i just find my solution **/^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(1[7-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9])$/ ** can you tell is this correct

Comment: you can replace 2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9] by [2-4]\d

Comment: yes, is better to make groups like [2-4] to improve readability. Could you mark as closed, pls? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(1[7-9]|[2-9]\d)$
```

```js
var regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(1[7-9]|[2-9]\d)$/g

console.log('12/25', regex.test('12/25'))
console.log('13/25', regex.test('13/25'))
console.log('01/18', regex.test('01/18'))
console.log('00/18', regex.test('00/18'))
console.log('01/18', regex.test('01/38'))
console.log('01/31', regex.test('01/38'))
```